How to delete a line in a text file with Python if it contains a certain word?
I have a text file structured as follows:
word 123 etc.
792 test abc
lorem ipsum word
92 testing
random 84
word 184 lmnop

Using Python, how can I delete every line that contains the word word?

# Open the input file for reading and create a new file for writing
with open("input.txt", "r") as input_file, open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    # Iterate through each line in the input file
    for line in input_file:
        # Check if the line contains the word "word"
        if "word" not in line:
            # Write the line to the output file if it does not contain "word"
            output_file.write(line)

